# Is it possible to take screenshots from Firefox for Android extension?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I wonder if there is a native api for taking screenshots from extensions. I was reading in MDN but coudn't find anything (but maybe I didn't had the right keywords). And I'm reading about using canvas to "imitate" the visual elements of DOM and getting the dataUrl, but it will be better if there is something easier, faster, and making more similar results.

Any suggestion is welcome! Thaks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean the entire screen or just the browser content?

Comment: @Chris i would assume entire screen as they mention "native api".

Comment: The whole screen, but It would be acceptable if I can capture the browser current document, at least

Comment: @gal007 for browser current document thats simple html5 with a little escalted privs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/Canvas#Loading_a_remote_page_onto_a_canvas_element

Comment: To get the entire screen you'd need to use utilities provided by the OS. For example, on OS X you could run the [screencapture utility](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/screencapture.1.html) using the [child_process](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/system_child_process) module.

Comment: @gal007 did you figure this one out yet, im very curious to try it out i just dont have an android device to test on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this is how to take a native screenshot on android. Make sure you have a 2nd tab open, it will append the canvas to it.

It has 2 problems right now, it takes 30seconds to do the math, and the math is intensive so sometimes it crashes.

Second problem is it's not getting the root view, it seems to just take a screenshot of the firefox browser layer view, not even when keyboard or main menu is open is it showing. I need it to get root view so it gets keyboard, table menubar etc etc. So working on that.

But here's the code, can copy paste it to scratchpad and run, wait 30sec, then look in your 2nd tab, there will be a canvas appended to the document.

https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/cb6e7c3a102784d04262